# PHP Map keys (arrays) Remove by numeric doesn't work?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my Map class:

```
/**
 * Map
 *
 * Collection of items, with a key.
 * @Author Jony <artemkller@gmail.com>
 */

Class Map
{
    /**
     * Annonymous Constructor
     * Sets up the array.
     */

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->map = array();
    }

    /**
     * Method add
     * Adds a new item to the collection with a key.
     *
     * Note: Key can NOT be numeric!
     *
     * @param key       The key of the item.
     * @param value     The value of the item.
     * @return void
     */

    public function add($key, $value)
    {
        $this->map[$key] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Contains
     * Checks if an item with specific key exists.
     *
     * @param key The key.
     * @return Boolean
     */

    public function contains($key)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($key))
        {
            return (isset($this->map[$key])) ? true : false;
        }
        else
        {
            $values = array_values($this->map);
            return (isset($values[$key])) ? true : false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method remove
     * Removes an item from the collection by key.
     *
     * @param key   The key of the item.
     * @return void
     */

    public function remove($key)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($key))
        {
            if (isset($this->map[$key]))
                unset($this->map[$key]);
        }
        else
        {
            $values = array_values($this->map);
            if (isset($values[$key]))
            {
                unset($values[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method get
     * Gets an item from the collection by key.
     *
     * Note: If entered numeric, it will get the key 
     * by it's offset position number. Arrays starting from 0.
     *
     * @param key The key of the item
     * @return Array item value (Either String, Integer, Object).
     */

    public function get($key)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($key))
        {
            return (isset($this->map[$key])) ? $this->map[$key] : null;
        }
        else
        {
            $values = array_values($this->map);
            return (isset($values[$key])) ? $values[$key] : null;
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to create my own Map type array class (from Java) just for practice and usage sometimes.

Now I am having problems with the contains / remove method.

When I don't use numeric remove/contains it works all fine, the error is mostly with the remove.

When I remove an item by offset (numeric), I don't think it gets removed from the actual array.

Okay, now let's debug it and test.

```
                $d = new Map();
                $d->add("heyy", 55);
                $d->remove(0);
                if ($d->contains(0))
                {
                    echo 5555;
                }
```

Creating a new map object, adding a new value, removing offset 0, checking if exists, if yes `echo 5555`.

**Now, let's do var_dump($values[$key]); after delete:**

Result: `NULL`

**Before delete:**

Result: `55`

**Now let's echo $this->map("heyy") after delete:**

Result: `55`

Okay, now it means that the item is not getting removed from the array itself.

What I've tried:

```
            $values = array_values($this->map);
            if (isset($this->map[$values[$key]]))
            {
                unset($this->map[$values[$key]]);
            }
```

Still doesn't work.

*What is wrong with this?*

Comment: @rid At the end of the code I tried removing the value of the offset from the array, I even tried doing it like this with string: "".$values[$key].""

Comment: Nope, 0 means offset 0, array_values gets the value of the array item by offset. so $values[0] = $This->map["heyy"]

Comment: array_values creates a new array - hence the map field still contains you key 0.

Comment: Now if you'd rename your methods and implement the `ArrayAccess` interface, your Map would be usable as an array replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `array_keys()`, not `array_values()`, because you need to unset the key, not the value. Example:

```
$map = array('abc' => 'def');
var_dump($map);
```

```
array(1) {
  ["abc"]=>
  string(3) "def"
}
```

```
$keys = array_keys($map);
if (isset($map[$keys[0]])) {
    unset($map[$keys[0]]);
}
var_dump($map);
```

```
array(0) {
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, does the same when changing to array_keys.

Comment: yeah I figured it out already haha, I also had to check if $values exists before the check, because getting undefined warning. But yeah that works.

Comment: Yeah but it gives me a warning that $values[$key] is undefined at this code which doesn't do unset: return (isset($this->map[$values[$key]])) ? true : false;

Answer (score 0):

```
public function remove($key)
{
    // First convert numeric key to the actual key at that position
    if (is_numeric($key))
    {
        $keys = array_keys($this->map);
        $key = $keys[$key];
    }
    // Now remove the key
    unset($this->map[$key]);
}
```